# Google -java-format Code formatter for java Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-java-format

I installed google-java-format in Intellij and made sure its enabled for current project. However its still not working, CTRL+ALT+L, which is by default in Intellij is still working.

Also, does this formatter shows error if formatting is wrong. Like eslint shows error if you leave trailing space in vs code.

Or anyone can suggest better formatter or any other way, guidance is appreciated. Though i make sure to do CTRl+ALT+L before pushing code, if my editor can highlight it in case i miss it, it would be great.

Thanks !!

Comment: We are using the google-java format in Intellij and it works as intended. Could it be that you just set it up on a project base instead of enabling it globally? 
The formatter just formats the code, it doesn't show errors.

Comment: The usual guide to install a format in Intellij should help setting everthing up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Feb 2023** with the latest google-java-format Intellij plugin we need to add following custom VM options. ( Go to Help -> Edit Custom VM Options )

```
-Xmx2018m
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Just follow the updated README file.
[Updated README file](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/blob/master/README.md#intellij-jre-config)

Comment: then you must restart the IDE and it will work correctly :)